# Undefined control sequence \ifnumcomp and idxlayout

Tags: indexing, idxlayout

I am struggling with `idxlayout` for generating a formatted index (my intent is to be able to group all subentries in one paragraph). Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{idxlayout}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Test}

Test\index{test}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

When I compile it

```
$ latex $docname
$ makeindex $idxfile
$ latex $docname
```

the last command fails with this error (and other subsequent errors):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\theindex ...umnnote}{}{\ila@prenote }}\ifnumcomp 
                                              {\theidxcols }{<}{\tw@ }{\...
l.1 \begin{theindex}
```

If I ignore the errors, I get a document with two indices (the first one is empty) and there are some symbols appearing around the second index (namely "2¡Θ" and "2¡Θ").

Could you help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you look in the `.log` file for the version number and release date of `etoolbox.sty`?

Comment: I get no problem if I compile the file.

Comment: According to the documentation, `\ifnumcomp` has been added to `etoolbox` in version 1.8, released 2009-08-06.

Comment: OK, that was the problem: my version was outdated (2008). I have updated etoolbox.sty and everything works fine now. Many thanks!

Comment: @mzi: You should update your whole TeX distribution, not just one package -- if some of your packages are from 2008, their might occur more inconsistencies

Answer (score 3):

Update your TeX distribution: the `\ifnumcomp` macro has been added to `etoolbox` in version 1.8, released 2009-08-06.

Note that just updating the package doesn't guarantee everything works, so it's better to upgrade the whole distribution.